# Inviting deceased relatives to a wedding

Tags: sources-mekorot, wedding, family-members

Can anybody send me the source for the custom of inviting deceased relatives (particularly grandparents) to a wedding.  I understand that Netai Gavriel discusses the issue but I have no access to that sefer.

Comment: I've never heard of this custom. How do you know it exists?

Comment: Don't have time to find the exact page, but here is access to Nitei Gavriel if you desire:
https://hebrewbooks.org/46545

Comment: Double AA;  I know of the custom since like many of our customs, I learned of it from my parents A'H, who we now want to invite to my son;s wedding.

Comment: chortkov2 Thank you.  The source is on page נ"ו at footnote י"ד

Answer (score 7):

I found a number of references to this custom

R Moishe Dovid Lebovits [here](https://www.thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol4Issue12.pdf) mentions

> Some bring down the custom for the chosson and kallah to go the cemetery to invite their non-living **grandparents** to the wedding
> (Refer to Yesod V’shoresh Hu’avoda Shar Hakollel 15:page 692 (new),
> Maharash Eingel 7:119:page 119, Yismach Lev 1:pages 54-55. Others do
> not have this custom (Derech Sicha 152)

R Avi Zakutinsky [here](https://outorah.org/p/27227/) mentions

> - The poskim tell us that the souls of the departed come to the wedding of their children and **grandchildren** (see Zohar Pinchas,
>   Shu”t Maharash Engel vol. 7 page 119, Yesod Veshoresh Haovodah Shaar
>   Hakolel 15, and Sefer Minhagim Chabad 75)
> - Many have the custom that if the chosson or kallah have lost one of their parents, the engaged child goes to the cemetery before the
>   wedding to extend an invitation to the parent who is deceased (see
>   Shulchan Haezer vol. 2 page 137 and Shu”t Mishnah Halachos 5:247).
>   Some write that the source for this custom is the Zohar (Minhag
>   Yisroel Torah on Nisuin page 137)
> - **It is unclear whether this custom extends to grandparents or other relatives** (see Sefer Derech Sicha page 152, Yismach Lev page
>   55, and Sefer Shaarei Nisuin Miluim 2). **The Shulchan Haezer writes
>   that the custom is to invite “the parents and the relatives.” It would
>   seem that he feels that this custom does extend to the grandparents.
>   However, Harav Yosef Shalom Elyashiv zt”l is of the opinion that one
>   need not invite the grandparents who are not alive** (Sefer Yivakshu
>   Mipihu page 478)